# taking out damaged small screws

Tags: wood, screws, wooden-furniture

I want to replace this 1 inch hinge on a decorative cabinet. the screws are pretty small and their head is damaged as you can see in the pictures. I can't get any leverage with the screw driver. Does anyone know how I can take these small screws out with out damaging the cabinet and ruining the wood?

[image]

Comment: Philips screwdrivers come in several sizes (P1, P2, P3, ...) it is important to use the correct sized screwdriver to match the screw. Also press hard inwards, even when unscrewing (especially when unscrewing). I'd replace with better screws - Pozidriv, Hex or Robertson screws - whatever is available locally. Slotted screws have even more variations in size, I'd avoid them other than for decorative effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a thin cutoff disk in a rotary tool (Dremel), cut a slot in each screw that fits a medium-sized flat-blade screwdriver.

Comment: Good tip I like that. If it was rusted metal I would have said drill them and use an easy-out but with wood this seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks!  how about using krazy glue and trying to glue the screw driver to the head of the screw? I am gonna get a Dremel eventually, but I came across this gluing technique and am wondering if gluing actually works ?!

Comment: Probably not. Cyanoacrylate doesn't harden well unless the mating surfaces are flat and tight. It's very difficult to achieve that in this situation. Maybe if you had a screwdriver that you were willing to cut off at the round shank and crated a flat disc to glue onto the screw....

Answer (score 1):

I like these screw remover bits from [sears](http://www.craftsman.com/craftsman-3-pc-screw-out-174-damaged-screw/p-00952154000P?sid=IDxCMDFx20140801x001&KPID=00952154000)
They have saved me a ton of trouble and are not very expensive.

Comment: Have to get me a set of these. They look useful.

Comment: do they come in small sizes for very fine screws?

Comment: They have small points to accommodate smaller screws. The drawback is that you have to drill a hole in a small screw, which is challenging.