# How can I remove this screw from a ps4 system?

Tags: screws

[image: The interior pattern of the screw is whethered away as you can see. This is on a ps4 system. I tried using different sized screws but to no use. Any ideas?][image: This is the adjacent screw in good condition]

The interior pattern of the screw is whethered away as you can see. This is on a ps4 system. I tried using different sized screws but to no use. Any ideas?

Comment: Which photo are you referring to? The second appears to be a simple Philips head. The first is a little hard to tell but appears to be a security head (pin in the middle preventing insertion of non-security bits. Beyond that, the photo is a little too dark to tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [taking out damaged small screws](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82726/taking-out-damaged-small-screws)

Comment: @DoxyLover he specifically said it's a damaged screw head

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I guess it's a reflection but it sure looks like a security pin to me.

Answer (score 4):

For that top picture's stripped screw-head you can first try a drill bit turned very slowly to hopefully catch the head and loosen it. Or, you can cut a slot in it with a Dremel cutting wheel to get a flat-head screwdriver in to remove it.

If neither of those work or are available, then you'll need the a Screw-Out kit, most hardware stores have them from Craftsman or another brand. They're basically a special drill bit designed to remove damaged screws...they do actually work.
[image: Craftsman Screw-Out]

Answer (score 0):

You need security bits for your screwdriver.

This kit:

https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B008HYVG6I/

Has the bits you need. It has pretty much any bit you will ever need for any electronics repair project; well worth the money.